# Haskell real-time update and lookup performance

Tags: arrays, performance, haskell, profiling, mutable

I am writing a game-playing ai (aichallenge.org - Ants), which requires a lot of updating of, and referring to data-structures. I have tried both Arrays and Maps, but the basic problem seems to be that every update creates a new value, which makes it slow.  The game boots you out if you take more than one second to make your move, so the application counts as "hard-real-time".  Is it possible to have the performance of mutable data-structures in Haskell, or should I learn Python, or rewrite my code in OCaml?

I have completely rewritten the Ants "starter-pack". Changed from Arrays to Maps because my tests showed that Maps update much faster.

I ran the Maps version with profiling on, which showed that about 20% of the time is being taken by Map updates alone.

Here is a simple demonstration of how slow Array updates are.

```
slow_array =
    let arr = listArray (0,9999) (repeat 0)
        upd i ar = ar // [(i,i)]
    in  foldr upd arr [0..9999]
```

Now evaluating slow_array!9999 takes almost 10 seconds!  Although it would be faster to apply all the updates at once, the example models the real problem where the array must be updated each turn, and preferably each time you choose a move when planning your next turn.

---

Thanks to nponeccop and Tener for the reference to the vector modules.  The following code is equivalent to my original example, but runs in 0.06 seconds instead of 10.

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as V

fast_vector :: IO (V.IOVector Int)
fast_vector = do
  vec <- V.new 10000
  V.set vec 0
  mapM_ (\i -> V.write vec i i) [0..9999]
  return vec

fv_read :: IO Int
fv_read  = do
  v <- fast_vector
  V.read v 9999
```

Now, to incorporate this into my Ants code...

Comment: Edit the question to reflect that you used the profiler, and provide wuth some sample self-contained code that is slow, if it is possible. My answer is generic, and having a well written question may attract people fluent in performance tuning.

Comment: "Is it possible to have the performance of mutable data structures in Haskell?" The answer is Yes! Haskell can do that!

Answer (score 12):

First of all, think if you can improve your algorithm. Also note that the default `Ants.hs` is not optimal and you need to roll your own.

Second, you should use a [profiler](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/profiling.html) to find where the performance problem is instead of relying on hand-waving. Haskell code is usually much faster than Python (10-30 times faster, you can look at [Language Shootout](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/compare.php?lang=python3&lang2=ghc) for example comparison) even with functional data structures, so probably you do something wrong.

Haskell [supports mutable data](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Data_structures#Mutable_data) pretty well. See `ST` (state thread) and libraries for mutable arrays for the `ST`. Also take a look at [vectors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) package. Finally, you can use data-parallel haskell, haskell-mpi or [other ways of parallelization](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Concurrency_and_parallelism) to load all available CPU cores, or even distribute work over several computers.

Are you using compiled code (e.g. `cabal build` or `ghc --make`) or use `runhaskell` or `ghci`? The latter ones are bytecode interpreters and create much slower code than the native code compiler. See [Cabal reference](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/) - it is the preferred way to build applications.

Also make sure you have optimization turned on (`-O2` and [other flags](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/options-optimise.html)). Note that `-O` vs `-O2` can make a difference, and try different backends including the new LLVM backend (`-fllvm`).

Comment: The code is compiled, and I have run with profiling.  Nothing illuminating, except that updating the data-structures is taking 30%+.  Looking into state thread, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Updating arrays one element at a time is incredibily inefficient because each update involves making a copy of the whole array. Other data structures such as `Map` are implemented as trees and thus allow logarithmic time updates. However, in general updating functional data structures one element at a time is often sub-optimal, so you should try to take a step back and think about how you can implement something as a transformation of the whole structure at once instead of a single element at a time.

For example, your `slow_array` example can be written much more efficiently by doing all the updates in one step, which only requires the array to be copied once.

```
faster_array =
    let arr = listArray (0,9999) (repeat 0)
    in  arr // [(i,i) | i <- [0..9999]]
```

If you cannot think of an alternative to the imperative one-element-at-a-time algorithm, mutable data structures have been mentioned as another option.

Answer (score 2):

You are basically asking for mutable data structure. Apart from standard libraries I would recommend you lookup this:

- vector: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector

That said, I'm not so sure that you need them. There are neat algorithms for persitent data structures as well. A fast replacement for Data.Map is hash table from this package:

- unordered-containers: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers

Comment: unordered-containers is immutable data structures with hashing. (vector has both mutable and immutable vectors)

Comment: Tener, do you have a reference for these "neat" algorithms?

Comment: @GregO'Keefe - the unordered-containers link leads to a very good persistent map implementation.  Otherwise, Chris Okasaki's thesis and subsequent work (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) is a good starting point.  See also this question on StackExchange: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/whats-new-in-purely-functional-data-structures-since-okasaki

Comment: Thanks John, excellent references.  I have begun to absorb this stuff, though it may take some time!